# "Is a number prime?"

Tags: primes, ti-basic

I've come up with a very efficient way of finding if a number is prime, using TI-BASIC for use with TI-83/84/+/SE calculators. I am trying to optimize it however possible.

```
:Input "NUMBER: ",A
:If A<2 or fPart(A
:Then
:Disp "INVALID INPUT"
:Stop
:End
:0→B
:2→I
:While I<A and not(B
:If 0=fPart(A/I
:1→B
:I+2→I
:If I=4
:3→I
:End
:If B
:Disp "NOT"
:Disp "PRIME"
```

A few notes:

- Lines 2-6 are for validating input, and don't affect the effectiveness of the program.
- The closing `"`s on line 4 and the last two lines are not necessary, but I added them so the syntax would highlight nicely here.
- Lines 12-14 are for speeding up the loop doubly; instead of incrementing by `1` each time, it is by `2`, with the `If` to offset the `4` to `3` on the first run.
- The `not(B` was very efficient, to end the loop whenever a match to identify the number as a composite number is found.

Comment: In practice, if you have enough memory, the most optimal solution is to store a lookup table (of some kind) of prime numbers and look up the number being queried. This can be pre-calculated, or done by a sieve. A list of all primes up to 65,536 is enough to test all integers up to 4.3 billion by trial division.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not speak TI-BASIC, so I cannot review the style, coding conventions etc. But there are two possible optimizations:

- If a number `A` is composite then it must have a factor that is less than or
  equal to `√(A)`. So you can replace

  ```
    :While I<A and not(B
  ```

with:

```
    :√(A)→S
    :While I≤S and not(B
```

This  reduces the number of trial divisions substantially  if the input is a prime number.

- Check the divisibility by `2` first, and then loop just over the odd numbers
  `I = 3, 5, 7, ...`. This saves you from checking

  ```
    :If I=4
    :3→I
  ```

in each loop iteration.

Comment: I can't really change my code here now that it's posted, but I had `:While I²<A and not(B` but the square didn't copy over for some reason... and thanks for the second suggestion.

Comment: @Timtech: OK, but computing the square root once instead of `I^2` in each iteration is *usually* faster. But I don't know if that applies to your calculator.

Comment: Oh, that's right. I was just thinking in terms of looping up till `I`. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, no! `I` is updated every time; of course you need to re-calculate it.

Comment: @Timtech: My suggestion was to calculate `S = sqrt(A)` once, so that you don't have to calculate `I^2` in each iteration. `While I^2 < A` is *replaced* by `While I <= S`.

Comment: Oh, makes sense :3

Comment: @Timtech Another classic optimization is wheel factorization: check only the numbers congruent to 1 or 5, modulo 6.